# How can I choose the data structure for the given maze?

Tags: tree, breadth-first-search, depth-first-search, maze

I have maze problem as shown in the picture below.

You can consider this as 6x6 matrice and the goal is to find the exit for the specific colored block. Based on the maze problems I looked through, I think applying bfs might be a good idea instead of using dfs. However, I am confused about how can I implement a tree that can hold more than two nodes. Is there any other data structure I could use instead of tree? Maybe, graph? Besides, many questions are asked to apply bfs or dfs to solve maze problem but I have never seen a case that would apply A* search algorithm. What about it's efficiency and implementation? If you could give me a hint that I can progress, I'd be appreciated.

Here is the picture:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can implement an "M" way tree: http://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~holte/T26/m-way-trees.html

Answer (score 0):

Note on terminology: a graph is not a substitute for a tree, because a tree is a type of graph.  I think the word you are looking for is lattice.

I would implement this as a matrix-shaped lattice with X * Y nodes and each node with up to four connections (north, south, east, and west).  Start with connections between each and every node, then remove any connections that are between two nodes where one or both nodes is occupied by a wall.

Once you have a graph representing the problem, you can solve using something like [Dijkstra's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) or [various others](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem).